# Why does a negative margin on a flexbox not work after a float (on the opposite side)?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-float, margin

See the following demo:

```css
.float {float:right;width:30px;height:30px;background:red;}
.flex {display:flex;margin-left:-50px;}
.item {margin-left:50px;}
.inlineblock {margin-left:-50px;}
.inlineblock .item {display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<h2>Without float</h2>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
</div>

<h2>With float</h2>
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
</div>

<h2>With float and inline-block</h2>
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="inlineblock">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
</div>
```

Why does a negative left margin not work on a flexbox when it comes after a right-floated element? The negative left margin works if the float is not there, and if the flex is replaced by something else (eg with inline-block items).

Can understand why things might go wrong if it were a left-floated item, but I don't see how a float on the right could affect a margin on the left.

Comment: the short answer: flex create a formatting context unlike a simple block element. If you add overflow:hidden to the last block element it will behave the same as flex

Comment: Floats and flex containers don't mix well together. It's covered in various areas of the spec. Note that if you apply `width: 100%` to the flex container or use `display: inline-flex` instead, you see the results you expect.